# Manually adding files to package.json?

Tags: node.js, npm

I am building a test app using node.js
I have downloaded a couple of modules and created a package.json using

```
npm init
```

This creates a package.json that shows all downloaded packages but not my own simple basic module that also needs to be included in the project.

My own module is just one 'utils.js' file containing a few helper functions:

```
var Utils = function() {

};

Utils.prototype.logSomething = function(){
    console.log("Hey these utils are way beyond handy");
}

module.exports = Utils;
```

Do I need to add this file manually to package.json?

Comment: Do you plan to publish it on npm ? If not, you don't need to declare your own files in the package.json (only your dependencies)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you don't. If you need to use it somewhere else you would just use

```
var Util = require('path/to/util.js')
var util = new Util()

util.logSomething()
```

You could add it in many ways to your package.json, but that being to much overhead. Because the only thing you'd gain is that you could require it with a simple string like `var util = require('MyUtil')`. But really what `require` does here is first looking up `node_modules/` directory whether there is a `MyUtil` directory.

Go with requiring from path, since it's also a very natural thing.